# How to horizontal align <ul> pagination tags?

Tags: css

I have Joomla 3.4.5 + Virtuemart 3 + Template Purity III.
I have a problem with the "pages navigation" links. You can see the problem here:
http://alturl.com/ofbav [link broken]

The problem is the list `<ul>` is displayed vertically instead of horizontally.

I would like to know which css code I have to add to get horizontally and "normal" looking my pagination buttons.

Can some expert help me please?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure. Try like this.

```
.vm-pagination > ul > li
{
   display:inline-block;
   padding:0px 10px;
}
```

**EDIT:**

According to comment below if you want one code should solve both the problem then use it like below. In the above code i tried to apply only for the direct children list items. In your bottom page case it is not direct children. So change your code like below.

```
.vm-pagination ul > li
{
   display:inline-block;
   padding:0px 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I have the same problem with the pagination buttons at the bottom. I thought it will fix both, but not at all. Can you have a look please at the bottom of the page?

Answer (score 0):

You should put `list-style: none;` on "ul" to get rid of the bullet points and `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;` on the contained "li"s to display them in a row.

```
.vm-pagination ul li
{
   list-style: none;
}

.vm-pagination ul li
{
   display: inline;
}
```

Then you can play with marging+paddings+borders to make them look more like tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `text-align: left;` to your pagination `ul`. Also you can disable list styling with `list-style: none;`. And as a final step, you can remove unnecessary paddings and margins of your `ul` element

`.vm-pagination > ul {
    text-align: none;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;

}`

Answer (score 0):

use in your style may help you

```
ul
{
list-style:none;
margin:0px 0px;
padding:0px 0px;
}
ul li
{
float:left;
padding:4px 4px;
}
```